# Scaffolded tests failing with ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4.1.6, I'm getting `InvalidAuthenticityToken` errors when running the tests generated with scaffold. Is there any way to disable the authenticity token check for a specific test?

```
rails g scaffold user name:string email:string password_digest:string
rake
```

Output:

```
...

  1) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_create_user:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

...
```

This is the source code:

```
test "should create admin_user" do
  assert_difference('Admin::User.count') do
    post :create, admin_user: { email: @admin_user.email, password_digest: @admin_user.password_digest, username: @admin_user.username }
  end

  assert_redirected_to admin_user_path(assigns(:admin_user))
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some options:

-> You can change behaviour of detecting CSRF invalid token to reseting session (like it was in Rails 3):

In `application_controller.rb`

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

to

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

-> You can do that with conditional expression, something like:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
else 
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

However this gave you a little bit different configuration for test and for dev/production env.

-> You can provide authenticity token manually in tests:

```
def set_form_authenticity_token
  session[:_csrf_token] = SecureRandom.base64(32)
end
```

And in particular test:

```
post :create, admin_user: { email: @admin_user.email, password_digest: @admin_user.password_digest, username: @admin_user.username }, authenticity_token:  set_form_authenticity_token
```

-> You can write your own helper, something like:

```
def set_form_authenticity_token
  session[:_csrf_token] = SecureRandom.base64(32)
end

alias_method :post_without_token, :post
def post_with_token(symbol, args_hash)
  args_hash.merge!(authenticity_token: set_form_authenticity_token)
  post_without_token(symbol, args_hash)
end
alias_method :post, :post_with_token
```

Comment: I couldn't get `form_authenticity_token` to work, I guess because it is a protected method. I was able to pass the test by setting `session[:_csrf_token]` directly with `SecureRandom.base64(32)` (this is what `form_authenticity_token` do) and passing the same value as the `authenticity_token` param in the post data. Seems hackish, but I'm not sure what else to do. Thanks for replying.

Comment: I've edited my answer - now it should work and doesn't seems such hackish ;)

Comment: defaulting the args_hash would be helpful 
``def post_with_token(symbol, args_hash = {})``

Comment: +1! Thanks one more time. I've added to `session[:_csrf_token]` to environments and eliminate `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error in my tests.